# React Page is not re-rendering while change in state in iOS version 16.4 and below

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone

Below is simple code to change state when page loads. But I am facing the problem of state change not updating in iOS 16.4 and below versions.
Does anyone know is any issue is there with iphone below version 16.4?
in iphone above 16.4, I am getting output as "check ok"
But in iphone ver 16.2, I am getting output as "ckeck initial".

```
export default function Article(props) {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState('ckeck initial');
  useEffect(()=>{
    setCheck('check ok');
  }, []);
return (
    < div>{check}</div>
)}
```